# How download if variable is set, and not download if unset

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an iCalendar file via querying the database, so I don't have to make new iCalendar files with every event created.

```
<?php

    header("Content-type: text/calendar");

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventID = '{$eventID}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // Render iCal file

?>
```

How to forbid file download if `$_GET["eventID"]` is not set?

In that case, I want instead of downloading, the visitor to get a blank page for an example.

Comment: Your question deals with an if statement essentially, not with the abortion of an already started download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick this at the top:

```
if (!isset($_GET["eventID"])) {
    exit;
}
```

You should also do something after the SQL query, checking that it has actually returned a result. e.g.

```
if ($numrows == 0) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: So, using "exit" will prevent file download? That's all, actually?!

Comment: you dont stop the download, you simply dont start it

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!isset($_GET["eventID"])){
echo 'bad';
}else{

// your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper thing to do is the send a 404 Not Found HTTP status code if the URL/entity doesn't exist:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$event  = $result->fetch_assoc();

if (!$event) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

header("Content-type: text/calendar");

echo $event['title'];
..
```

Here I'm checking whether the event exists in the database. To handle a missing `$_GET` parameter you could send a *400 Bad Request* separately.